# How to use options in passwd command

Tags: command-line

```
OPTIONS
   -d, --delete        delete the password for the named account (root only)

   -f, --force         force operation (effectively calls `chfn'?)

   -k, --keep-tokens   keep non-expired authentication tokens

   -l, --lock          lock the named account (root only)

   -S, --status        report password status on the named account (root only)

   --stdin             read new tokens from stdin (root only)

   -u, --unlock        unlock the named account (root only)
```

How to use these commands? when type these command there is no response its just displaying the same thing again.

For example when I type

```
passwd -d Madhu G
```

there is no response or error.

Comment: Whats the output of `whoami` ? Also is there a user named `Madhu G` in your system ?

Comment: Since there cannot be an userID with space in it, "Madhu G" is not valid. UserID in Ubuntu are generally all lowercase. Also deleting your own password is not a terrific idea.

Answer (score 2):

All linux command has the same structural syntax writing

```
command [-options] [attr]
```

and passwd is not else

```
passwd [options] [LOGIN]
```

So for example I'm gonna list some uses of options

Delete(make it empty) an account password using the -d option

```
$ sudo passwd -d guest

passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

**Now for your case above** first you dont' use `sudo` and also be sure of using correct user name  `Madhu G`? Since I dont think that you can have a username with space between

Another Example   expire the account password using -e option

```
$ sudo passwd -e guest

passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

Comment: +1 And sorry that I also write an answer. ;)

Comment: @A.B. don't be so, you have the right to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is wrong.

```
passwd -d Madhu G
```

`passwd` accepts this:

```
passwd [options] [LOGIN]
```

Your command deviates from this requirement and, therefore, a list of possible parameters will be displayed:

```
$ passwd -d Madhu G  
Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -a, --all                     report password status on all accounts
  -d, --delete                  delete the password for the named account
  -e, --expire                  force expire the password for the named account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --keep-tokens             change password only if expired
  -i, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -l, --lock                    lock the password of the named account
  -n, --mindays MIN_DAYS        set minimum number of days before password
                                change to MIN_DAYS
  -q, --quiet                   quiet mode
  -r, --repository REPOSITORY   change password in REPOSITORY repository
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -S, --status                  report password status on the named account
  -u, --unlock                  unlock the password of the named account
  -w, --warndays WARN_DAYS      set expiration warning days to WARN_DAYS
  -x, --maxdays MAX_DAYS        set maximum number of days before password
                                change to MAX_DAYS
```

Correct syntax, but still wrong because with space and not lowercase:

```
sudo passwd -d "Madhu G"
```

For your account (bad idea)

```
sudo passwd -d "$USER"
```

or for another login name (without spaces and with lowercase):

```
sudo passwd -d <username>
```